# LVM: failed logical volume removing from VG after disk was detached

Tags: linux, lvm

The old storage device for backup was upgraded to new one.
An old storage device was unmounted and detached from server, but NOT removed from LVM.
This backup device was in separated VG and LV.
I tried to remove it from LVM many times.
But in any case got an error:

```
# lvremove --force --verbose /dev/backup/backup
    Using logical volume(s) on command line.   WARNING: Device for PV 1u0Cil-JrpS-6O9A-YqID-8CBh-v05T-7KEF3G not found or rejected by a filter.
    There are 1 physical volumes missing.
    Archiving volume group "backup" metadata (seqno 3).
    Releasing logical volume "backup".
  Aborting vg_write: No metadata areas to write to!
```

How to fix this problem?
It it safe to reboot server?